# Java server with Firebase and Google App engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, firebase, server

I am slightly confused with the Firebase client library that is available for Java. In the documentation, it says that the library should be used on the server. Recently, I came across Google App Engine. A PaaS service that allows application code to be put in the cloud.

Could I write the server code using the Firebase client library and deploy that as application code on Google App Engine? That way my application could connect with Firebase through the App engine.

I am asking this questions from the perspective of creating a Java application; the same libraries available for Android are not available for Java desktop applications. The only library that can be used in Java is the server library.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

That is possible with the firebase-server-sdk.

You find an example deploying a servlet to appengine and access firebase from within the servlet here: https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/firebase-app-engine-android-studio

Just skip the android stuff and scroll down to MyServlet source code.

[But be aware of the scaling setting you need to use firebase on app engine.](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/firebase-app-engine-android-studio#configuring_the_app_engine_backend_to_use_manual_scaling)